# How to show pin marker landmark on top

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I show a pin marker landmark on top? Because I have many markers on the map, how can I show a pin landmark on top?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setZindex()` method for the marker to give it a higher z-index.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

You can dynamically set the z-index by setting an event listener on the markers for the `mouseover` event.

Comment: I don't know how I use setZindex()
Exam please.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site/code?  You need to understand how to write JavaScript using the Google Maps API.